# How do I assign object to generically typed property of a reactive proxy?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a class I can use to load data asynchronously. Instances of this class are used in a Pinia store and watched by Vue components to enable automatic UI updates when data is loaded.

However, I get a compile-time error:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'UnwrapRef<T> | undefined'
```

Here's the code:

```
export class AsyncData<T> {
    state: AsyncDataState
    data?: T

    constructor(request?: Promise<T>) {
        if (request) {
            this.state = AsyncDataState.Loading

            // use reactive proxy to modify state later in case anyone is listening
            const reactiveThis = reactive(this)

            request.then(d => {
                // got it
                reactiveThis.state = AsyncDataState.Loaded
                reactiveThis.data = d // <= ERROR
            },
            reason => {
                // no dice
                reactiveThis.state = (reason == DataError.NotFound ? AsyncDataState.NotFound : AsyncDataState.LoadFailed)
            })
        }
        else {
            this.state = AsyncDataState.New
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert on the mysteries of Typescript or Vue 3, but it seems to me I should be able to assign a value of type T to the property on a reactive wrapper corresponding to a property of type T.

What am I missing?

Comment: Actual the `reactiveThis` wouldn't work because the constructor returns `this` not `reactiveThis`.

Answer (score 0):

`reactive` is designed for plain object, so it will lose the type definition.

And the `reactiveThis` in your constructor wouldn't work, because the constructor returns this not reactiveThis. So nobody can "listen" this reactive variable.

Here is my optimized version:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import type { Ref } from 'vue';

export class AsyncData<T> {
  state: Ref<AsyncDataState> = ref(AsyncDataState.New)
  data?: T

  constructor(request?: Promise<T>) {
      if (request) {
          this.state.value = AsyncDataState.Loading

          request.then(d => {
              // Notice: Make sure the assignments of this.data always before this.state
              // because when this.state changes, effect triggers immediately
              this.data = d
              this.state.value = AsyncDataState.Loaded
          },
          reason => {
              // no dice
              this.state.value = (reason == DataError.NotFound ? AsyncDataState.NotFound : AsyncDataState.LoadFailed)
          })
      }
      else {
          this.state.value = AsyncDataState.New
      }
  }
}
```

Only the `state` is reactive, and `data` keep the type definition.Then it can be used as below:

```js
import { effect } from 'vue';

const p = fakePromise<Cat>();
const data = new AsyncData<Cat>(p);

effect(() => {
  if (data.state.value === AsyncDataState.Loaded) {
    console.log('receive new data', data.data);
  } else {
    console.log('check data', data.data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you say the `reactiveThis` "wouldn't work". Per the Vue3 [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-proxy-vs-original-1), "calling reactive() on the same object always returns the same proxy". By the time the promise continuations executes (later), other code might have used `reactive()` to get a proxy and might be listening to `this`.

Comment: I can see the `effect` function is actually defined in `vue`, but I can't find any documentation for it. Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @BobMeyers `effect` is like a *listener*, when any reactive variable changes inside it, it will trigger. It is a low-level function for `watch` and `computed`. You can show me how do you want to use the `AsyncData`, so I can modify the usage demos.